# How to assign a static public IP to multiple Azure Function Apps

Tags: azure, function, ip, nat, gateway

I have a set of 10 Azure Function Apps which are connecting to an external system through a firewall. This firewall only allows an allowlist IP. I want to assign a static public IP to the Azure Function Apps and add it to the Firewall.

What I have done, is to deploy a NAT Gateway with a static public IP into a subnet and assign it to a Function. However, it only allows to assign the subnet to a single Azure Function App. It is not valid for 10 Azure Function Apps and I will have to create so many NAT Gateways/PublicIP/Subnets as Azure Function Apps I have.

Comment: When you say Functions, I assume you mean Function Apps?

Comment: Reading your post again: are you looking for an option to have one statis _inbound_ IP address, or one static _outbound_ IP address?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is only for one static outbounf IP address (the injest traffic is not relevant at this point)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps to assign static Outbound IP for functions.

1. Deploy a function app in Premium or App Service Plans.
   [image]
2. After creating function app go to Networking and configure VNET.
   [image]

[image]

[image]

3. After configuring VNet you can go to Subnet details and find NSG and NAT details over their
   [image]

[image]

4. After that you also need to add **WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL** in the configuration settings.
   [image]

[image]

for further details you can go through the [VNet integration](https://notetoself.tech/2020/11/21/azure-functions-with-a-static-outbound-ip-address/) document.

Also there are many documents with similar discussions.

1. [Outbound IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#find-outbound-ip-addresses)
2. [NAT Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway)
3. [Static IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-faq#how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-in-functions-)

Comment: what value should I enter in Subnet Address Block (CIDR Block) ?